# Смайл и смайлик — одно и то же?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Я говорю о стилизованном графическом изображение человеческого лица. В английском для этого есть термин smiley, на русский его перевели словом "смайлик". Однако в русскоязычной литературе в том же значении употребляется слово "смайл". Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Сначала мне в бумажной переписке очень **смайлов** не хватало. [А. В. Жвалевский, Е. Пастернак. Время всегда хорошее (2009)]

Насколько это корректно?

Comment: Да, "смайлик" уменьшительное, которое сразу стало основным вариантом. А вот когда говорят "ссыль", образованное от якобы уменьшительного "ссылка", тогда становится даже не смешно, а скорее неприятно.

Comment: Вот ещё: http://www.rusyaz.ru/is/ns/smiley.html. В заголовке оба называния, а так преобладает "смайлик".

Answer (score 1):

Употребление обоих слов одинаково корректно. Оба слова присутствуют в словаре Лопатина, Викисловарь приводит их в качестве синонимов, Википедия в статье "Смайлик" упоминает оба слова.

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы большего. Словарь Лопатина — орфографический, авторитет Вики невысок.

Comment: Ну вот Вам большее. В "Словаре молодёжного сленга" доктора филологических наук Т.Г. Никитиной присутствует слово "смайл". Правда слова "смайлик" там нет.

Comment: @М_Г Укажите, пожалуйста, на каком основании Вы считаете слово "смайлик" корректным. Или Вы оба слова считаете некорректными? Тогда лучше уточнить вопрос.

Comment: На том основании (не вполне строгом, конечно), что 1) исходное  smiley словари переводят как "смайлик", 2) "смайлик" статистически преобладает.

Comment: В "Словаре молодёжного сленга" присутствует слово "смайл".  Правда слова "смайлик" там нет.  === А может,  смайлик — уже не сленг?

Comment: *1) исходное smiley словари переводят как "смайлик"* — дайте, пожалуйста, реквизиты словаря. По поводу 2) — это совершенно в порядке вещей, когда употребление одного из синонимов преобладает статистически.

Comment: *А может, смайлик — уже не сленг?* — это словарь 15-летней давности. Судя по Лопатину, уже ни то ни другое не сленг.

Comment: Давайте наоборот, Есть перевод smiley как смайл?

Comment: @М_Г Как Вам удобнее. Я давно не пользуюсь бумажными словарями, поэтому ссылку могу дать только на сетевой — [multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=+smiley+&l1=1), наиболее заслуживающий уважения среди них. Впрочем, в любом случае, ни один из сетевых словарей не является более авторитетным, чем отвергнутый Вами Викисловарь. Теперь Ваша очередь поделиться своими авторитетными источниками.

Comment: https://translate.google.co.il/?hl=en&tab=wT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=smiley

Answer (score 0):

Грамота подтверждает, что "смайл" тоже признан:

> Вопрос № 227443
>   Здравствуйте! Заметил, что у вас в словарях зафиксированы две формы английского слова smile: **смайл** и **смайлик**. А какой из этих вариантов лучше употребляться в официально-деловой речи, например, в файле помощи к программе? Спасибо!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Для Вашего примера возможны оба варианта.

Хотя в своих ответах Грамота чаще употребляет слово *смайлик* (14:2).

> Вопрос № 237471
>   Является ли **смайл** знаком препинания? Как его употреблять в предложении: после точки, вместо точки? Спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   **Смайлик** не является знаком препинания, и сочетание его со знаками препинания не регламентируется правилами правописания. Рекомендации веб-дизайнеров см. [здесь](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/143).

Comment: *...Грамота последовательно употребляет слово смайлик*  — Нет. Посмотрите ответы на вопросы 231595 и 246878. Вообще, я не припомню случая, чтобы Грамота отрицала слово из словаря Лопатина.